# Is there a problem with the recursive method?

Tags: pascal

I am trying to verify all elements of an array[1..199] if there are negative elements. This code doesn't verify first element of the array. I am obliged to do this by recursive method.

I tried to do a separate condition, but this didn't worked. I firstly made it with for and then changed to recursive method.

```
   Var a:array[1..100] of integer;n:integer;

        Function E(n:integer):boolean;
          Begin
           if n=0 then E:=False
            else if a[n]<0 then E:=True
             else E:=E(n-1);
          End;

     Begin
      readln(n);
      for i:=1 to n do
        readln(a[i]);
      writeln('Are there negative numbers in array? ',E(n));
      readln();
     End;
```

I expect the output true if there are any negative elements or false if there not.

Comment: why not use `for` loop instead of recursive method?

Comment: Where does array `a` come from, it is not passed to the function `E`?

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: I am obliged to use this method by the condition of problem. @Mr.Nimelo array a is a global variable. Calling the variable: writeln('Are there any negative numbers ?', E(n)), where n is reading from the program.

Comment: Could you provide us with the Minimal Working Example?

Comment: @Mr.Nimelo i edited the program. Hope i fulfilled Minimal Working Example.

Comment: In the updated example, you are missing the initialization of n and the array a.

Comment: @LURD what do you want to say? Sorry for the question, i didn't understood.

Comment: The example is not complete. Without valid value for the global variable n and and values in the array a, your example is meaningless.

Comment: You should also implement that the recursive function test the upper bounds of the array, in order to avoid range errors when accessing the array.

Comment: @LURD i added the reading of every variable from the program. Hope this helped.

Comment: Nick, your function should have been ok, that's what was puzzling me. And that is why it is important to present a question that can be verified by people trying to help.

Comment: @LURD thank you for your help, i am new to this site, and i want to learn from all of you, from your experiences. Thank you for you time used with me.

Comment: @Mr.Nimelo thank you too. Without you guys i would never understood how to write correct questions

Comment: The code you have provided doesn't show the error you claim it to have: *This code doesn't verify first element of the array.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not a `Pascal` expert but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
program Hello;
var 
arrayWithNegatives : array[1..10] of integer = (-1,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91);
arrayWithPositives : array[1..10] of integer = (0,20,30,40,50,60,71,80,90,91);
emptyArray : array of integer;

Function HasNegativeNumbers(a: array of integer; n:integer):boolean;
Begin
    if n < 0 then HasNegativeNumbers := False
    else if a[n] < 0 then HasNegativeNumbers := True
    else HasNegativeNumbers := HasNegativeNumbers(a, n - 1);
End;


begin
  writeln (HasNegativeNumbers(arrayWithNegatives, length(arrayWithNegatives) - 1));
  writeln (HasNegativeNumbers(arrayWithPositives, length(arrayWithPositives) - 1));
  writeln (HasNegativeNumbers(emptyArray, length(emptyArray) - 1))
end.
```

Comment: Mr.Nimelo, this isn't the error. The n=0 is the elementar example, that says where the recursive method stops. If i say n<0 it will be stack overflow error because the program will not know where to stop.

Comment: @NickDruta so why did you mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: @TomBrunberg i accepted the answer.  I resolved the problem, it was in other function, that inverses the array. Thank you for help